# formdata in ajax call

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, multipartform-data

When I pass formdata in ajax call after json return it does not return on Success or error block just printing value on browser

```
  //  And my Controller side code is

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create(InquiryModel model)
    {
        var inquiry = _inquiryService.GetInquiryById(model.Id);
         return Json(inquiry.Id, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

// View side


       var formData = new FormData();
        jQuery.each(jQuery('#QuotationDocument')[0].files, function (i, file) {
            formData.append('file-' + i, file);
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Inquiry")',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: "POST",

            success: function (data) {
                alert("ssss");
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("error", msg.statusText + ". Press F12 for details");
            }
        });
```

when I pass only formData it works fine

Comment: Show how your calling the ajax function?

Comment: datatype: "json", add this parameter in ajax function and try

Comment: Show your model class ?

Comment: I add datatype : "json" but its not working

Answer (score -1):

Try like this;

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Inquiry")',
            data: formData,
            datatype: "json",
            type: "POST",

            success: function (data) {
                alert("ssss");
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("error", msg.statusText + ". Press F12 for details");
            }
        });
```